# Allow dynamic subdomain in url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have created a virtual host www.maindomain.com for my site. I want to allow dynamic sub domains in the url using htaccess i.e test.maindomain.com, abc.maindomain.com, etc should be allowed. My site folder structure is www/test/index.php.

Here is my current htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? index.php?url=%1&path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]    
</IfModule>
```

I get Server not found and could not connect error messages.

Can anyone suggest me a good solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These subdomains need to be registered first

Answer (score 0):

If your server is online:

You need a [Wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) plus a Wildcard `serverAlias` in your VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.local
    DocumentRoot "/my_server/htdocs"
    ServerName example.local
    ServerAlias *.example.local
    # [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally you will be able to catch those subdomains in your `.htaccess` file.